# assembly reference for BindingContext

Tags: c#, windows

what is assembly reference for BindingContext? i use this code in c# win app, but it gives me error

```
 txt_barcode_num_pri.BindingContext .ToString  (TextBox).UpdateSource();

                if (txt_barcode_num_pri.GetBindingExpression(c).HasError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this [BindingContext Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.aspx)

You can find `BindingContext` under *Namespace* `System.Windows.Forms` in *Assembly*, `System.Windows.Forms` (in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

Try using the code this way:

```
var bindingContext = txt_barcode_num_pri.BindingContext[dataSource];
```

Where *dataSource* is the `DataSource` object.

OR

```
var bindingContext = txt_barcode_num_pri.BindingContext[dataSet, "DataMember"];
```

Comment: is syntax of line 1 is true?

Comment: Can you further elaborate your code what are you trying to achieve? Also it would be helpful if you format your code for better understanding.

Comment: this code is exist in wpf,because i want to use activex in my project and i couldn t use activex in wpf,so i transfer my code to win app c#,and this line gives me error in this environment

Comment: See my edited answer. This may help you regarding the proper use of BindingContext.